# URL Variable passing into Curl

Tags: c++, curl

I'm new to cURL and needed it for my assignment. And I'm using C++ for this.

I have this particular line which works fine.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
```

But my problem occurs when I modify the URL into variable. i.e

```
string URL = "http://www.google.com";  
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
```

My program crashes. Anyone can point to me what's my mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> CURLOPT_URL: Pass in a pointer to the actual URL to deal with. The parameter should be a char * to a zero terminated string...

If you hold the URL in a `std::string` variable you should use `std::string::c_str()`.

```
std::string URL = "http://www.google.com";  
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
```

Comment: It works, thank you alot. But could you explain to me what is the meaning "should be a char * to a zero terminated string"