# C++ curl could not resolve host if URL is provided as argument

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am building a small application which needs to do get requests to an API.

I use libcurl which works great if I provide the complete URL directly within the function, but if I do it inside of a function with the URL as a parameter it fails instantly with the error CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST(6).

So I know it's not a DNS problem since I can resolve it if I provide the URL directly.

Here is my current function.

```
std::string winget(std::string url)
{

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
        return readBuffer;
}

//and I call it like this :

winget("example.org");
```

Basically if I directly replace the url param in the function with "example.org" it works. So I don't really know what to do with it.

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution here: [URL Variable passing into Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397120/url-variable-passing-into-curl)

Basically you need to provide the URL as a null-terminated string. So if the parameter is a string, use `.c_str()` or get a `char*` from that string.

Comment: Same problem might also occur with other parameters for curl. Remember that libcurl ist a C library, not a C++ library. That means that libcurl cannot use `std::string` for strings. Instead, `char*` is used for any string-like content.