# How to pass variable with URL to libcurl

Tags: c++, variables, libcurl

I have this line:

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://bk-bestgamer.ru/get.php?get=hello");`

it works fine. i send request and receive a line that contains text "hello" from my site.
but when i do like this

```
std::string url;
std::cin >> url;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());`
```

after that, when i use

```
curl_easy_perform(curl);`
```

i have an error
"protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl".
i tried to do following

```
char url[] = "https://bk-bestgamer.ru/get.php?get=hello";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);`
```

it doesn't work with the same error.
i really do not know what to do.
i found some recommendations there
[URL Variable passing into Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397120/url-variable-passing-into-curl)
you can see, i tried that, but it doesn't succeed.

i've tried to compile the same code in ubuntu, where i have libcurl with ssl. but it doesn't work with the same error. from linux command line it works correctly.

Comment: Does it work for you if you use `curl` from the command line? there is a chance your curl wasn't compiled with SSL enabled. If you compiled `curl` manually make sure you did `./configure --with-ssl` prior to `make`.

Comment: @arboreal84 thanks, but i use windows, so i have no ./configure. from the command line in windows all works correctly. also from code, when i set url directly in quotes, it works. it returns error only when passing variable with url.

Comment: @KirillBelousov That's not possible, so something else is going on. Post a complete example that shows the behaviour you see, and post the commands you use to compile it.

Comment: Your error message says you have problem with https support and not passing  url as parameter. Complete example would help. Looks like you have curl version withou ssl support (there are multiple downloads for win also - some of them does not support ssl).

Comment: @pe3k okay, i will add full example which doesn